# edit strongly typed dropdownlist through model binding in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my model declare selectcountrylist,lstcountry and countryname properties..,

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "StudentName Is Required")]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CountryName Is Required")]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public int StateID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "StateName Is Required")]
        public string StateName { get; set; }

        public int CityID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CityName Is Required")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> lstCountry { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> lstState { get; set; }

        public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }

    }
```

By creating the object by using reference call the properties but in the all fields selected value is zero in list

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int studentID)
        {
            Student studentobj = new Student();
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                Con.Open();
                try
                { 
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EditStudent", Con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentID);
                    SqlDataReader _Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   while( _Reader.Read())
                    {
                        studentobj.StudentName = _Reader["StudentName"].ToString();
                        studentobj.CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(_Reader["CountryID"]);
                        studentobj.CountryName = _Reader["CountryName"].ToString();
                        studentobj.StateName = _Reader["StateName"].ToString();
                        studentobj.CityName = _Reader["CityName"].ToString();                 
                      studentobj.lstCountry = GetCountry();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Con.Close();
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
            return View(studentobj);
        }
```

in view overide the select value from database,instead of select value it show the list..,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryName , new SelectList(Model.lstCountry, "Value", "Text"), "select")
```

Comment: Format your question better. Please.

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryName , new Model.lstCountry, "select")` - creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless. And the last parameter of `DropDownListFor()` adds html attributes (and adding `Model.SelectedCountry` makes no sense) What is your question?

Comment: edit the code pls observe that..,

Comment: Stephen Muecke Edit the dropdown through model binding